# Image Filter and Show text on Mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover

I have a set of images that when moused over need to change to a change do a dark grey and lower opacity, and pop up predefined text.
Is this doable with CSS only? or do I need use Jquery?
How would I go about this?
Thanks.

Comment: You want the image itself to change, or for a partially-transparent layer to appear *over* the image? And where would the predefined text be coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with css only:

HTML:

```
<div class="hover-div">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
    <div class="hover-text">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="hover-div">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
    <div class="hover-text">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
     ​
```

css:

```
div.hover-div{
    display:block;
height:200px;
 width:400px;   
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

div.hover-div:hover .hover-text{
    display:block;        
}

div.hover-div:hover img{
    opacity:0.8;        
}

.hover-text{
    display:none;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:-20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:white;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}​
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/hueBt/1/

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/oqocic/2/edit)*

CSS only:

css:

```
  .box{
    position:relative;
    background:#444;
    width:160px;
    height:200px;
  }
  .box span{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
  }
  
  .box:hover img{
    opacity:0.4;
  }
  .box:hover span{
    display:inline;
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img1.jpg">
    <span>This is the description 1</span>  
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img2.jpg">
    <span>This is the description 2</span>  
  </div>
```